# as_xml in model not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to respond with json and xml in my ruby on rails app.
In my controller (e.g "Person") I have:

```
respond_to :html, :json, :xml
```

In the show-method:

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
respond_with @person
```

In my Person-Model I define a 'as_json' and a 'as_xml' method, because I want to include data.

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(:include => :parents)
end
def as_xml(options={})
  super(:include => :parents)
end
```

The call /persons/1.json is correct.
But the call /persons/1.xml gives me only the person attributes as an xml. The include is missing.

I can't find informations for xml, only for json. Is it possible to use as_xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are searching for [to_xml](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-to_xml)

Answer (score 0):

Like lucapette already suggested, you might want to use `to_xml`

You can do something like this in your model to get custom xml (or json) output

```
def to_xml options = {}
  return generate_output_object.to_xml options
end

def generate_output_object
  return {"myobject" => {"special_processing" => get_special_data}}
end
```

Comment: `to_xml` was the correct hint.  
I used a bit different way:  
`alias_method :ar_to_xml, :to_xml  
def to_xml(options = {})  
  options[:include] = [:parents]  
  ar_to_ml(options)  
end`